# How to access DataTable by "coordinates" in simple matrix?

Tags: c#, matrix, datatable, naming, datarow

I'm trying to use a simple matrix data structure, but I need to access it via **strings**, so a `int[,] array` does not the thing. What I want to do is this:

[image: simple matrix]

then, access it like:

```
int value = table[B,C];
```

DataColumns allows naming of the colums, but DataRows seems not. I am missing something?

Comment: Rows have no names - no more than database rows or Excel rows do. In general, items in an array or collection have indexes.  `table[12]["A"]` will return the value stored in column `A` of the 13th row

Answer (score 0):

Well finally scraped DataTable an used a nested Hashtable and a custom get method to ask for the data.

```
Hashtable hashTable = new Hashtable();
Hashtable dataTable = new Hashtable();

dataTable.Add("key2",25);
hashTable.Add("key1",dataTable);
```